# TimeZone changes when creating google calendar event

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

When I add a calendar event, it is off by 1 hour after DST changed.

I have been adding calendar events to my google calendar from google sheets in bulk, but after the daylight saving change, it become messed up. It appears in my Execution log that the time starts in "GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)", but later changes to "GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" which I believe messes it up, but I am unsure.

I was using this as a guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#reference

Explanation: Basically I am writing in my own timestamp and extracting the values from Google Sheets and making a calendar event for it.

[image]

To create a calendar event, you need a starting and ending date/time. For purposes of this thread, Here is a small snippet of just the STARTING date/time with the accompanying log output after it:

`var startDate = sheet.getRange(i + 1,2).getValue()`

- Label: #1
- Log: Sun Nov 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

`var startTimeHour = sheet.getRange(i + 1,3).getValue()`

- Label: #2
- Log: 5

`var startTimeMin = sheet.getRange (i + 1,4).getValue()`
`var startTimeMin = (startTimeMin / 60)`

- Label: #3
- Log:  0.9166666666666666
- Notes: I am taking the value of 55 and dividing by 60 to convert it to hours

`var startTime = new Date(startDate.getTime() + ((startTimeHour + startTimeMin) * 60 * 60 * 1000))`

- Log: Sun Nov 06 2022 04:55:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
- Notes:
  startDate.getTime() = 1667707200000 and is milliseconds for time since 1/1/1970

((startTimeHour + startTimeMin) * 60 * 60 * 1000)) = 21300000, the 5 hours 55 minutes I want, converted to milliseconds

This is where it gets tricky. I am adding 5 hours 55 minutes to essentially 12AM, which should be 5:55 AM, but it comes up as 4:55 AM, and somehow the timezone is now Eastern Standard Time instead of Eastern Daylight Time. So basically the command can be simplified to `new Date(1667728500000)`.

`start: {dateTime: startTime.toISOString()}`

- Log: startTime.toISOString() = 2022-11-06T09:55:00.000Z
- Notes: This is what I use with the Calendar API to post it to my calendar

And again, this will add to my calendar as `11/6/2022 4:55 AM`, which is incorrect. I need it to be 5:55 AM.

Comment: `startTimeHour + startTimeMin` does not seem appropriate. `startTimeHour * 60 + startTimeMin` seems more suitable.

Comment: You're suggesting: (((startTimeHour * 60) + startTimeMin) * 60 * 60 * 1000)) ?

Comment: `(((startTimeHour * 60) + startTimeMin) * 60 * 1000))`

Comment: @Aaron, if you convert 1667707200000 to UTC, it's `Sunday, November 6, 2022 4:00:00 AM`. Plus the 5h 55 min it matches your end result (`2022-11-06T09:55:00.000Z`). Since the change of EDT to EST happened between 06AM-07AM UTC, the calculation is correct. You must add an hour to compensate for the time change.

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes sense then. If UTC officially changes it at 06AM-07AM then that is why I got messed up between that exact time. I was going off my computer which changed at 01AM-2AM EDT!

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the time change.

> On the first Sunday in November, at 2:00 a.m. EDT, clocks are moved back to 1:00 a.m. EST

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone#:%7E:text=On%20the%20first%20Sunday%20in%20November%2C%20at%202%3A00%C2%A0a.m.%20EDT%2C%20clocks%20are%20moved%20back%20to%201%3A00%C2%A0a.m.%20EST)

Your calculations are right, but your event starts before the time change and ends after hence the change from EDT to EST and the appearance of being off by an hour.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer, because the source you linked says it changes on 2 AM EDT where my event doesn't take place until 5:55 AM EDT. With that in mind, my event doesn't start before the change.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and documentation, using UTC as a base timezone since it is not affected by daylight changes, if you convert 1667707200000 to UTC (using epochconverter.com for example), it results in `Sunday, November 6, 2022 4:00:00 AM`.

Adding the 5h 55 min it matches the result (2022-11-06T09:55:00.000Z) from your code.

Since the change from EDT to EST happened to the equivalent time-frame of 06AM-07AM UTC, the calculation is correct.

To compensate for the change from Daylight to Standard Eastern time, you must add an hour to the end result.